# Nilpotent Lie algebras are closed under extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, central-extensions

**Problem**: Let $L$ be a Lie algebra and $K$ an ideal such that $L/K$ is nilpotent and such that $ad(x)|_K$ is nilpotent for all $x \in L$. Prove that $L$ is nilpotent.

By Engel's Theorem, I know that $K$ is nilpotent, which implies that $ad(K)$ is also nilpotent. So, there exists an integer $m$ such that $ad(K)^{(m)} = \{ 0 \}$, where $ad(K)^{(m)}= [ad(K), ad(K)^{(m-1)}]= \{ 0 \}$,  (the $m$-th term of the lower central series of $ad(K)$). Now, because I know that an extension of a nilpotent algebra is nilpotent only if it is central, I would like to relate $K$ to $Z(L)$, using information on $ad(K)^{(m)}$,  if that makes any sense.  Is this a reasonable way to tackle the problem? If so, any hints to proceed?

Comment: Is it for all $x\in K$ or for all $x\in L$? I think it is for all $x\in L$.

Comment: Thank you, I just edited.

Comment: Since you are invoking Engel's theorem, which is only valid in finite dimension, shouldn't you require $L$ to be finite-dimensional in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes provided that $L$ is finite-dimensional. Denote by $x^*$ a class in $L/K$, $x\in L$. Since $L/K$ is nilpotent, there exists $m$ such that $ad_{x^*}^r=0$. That is, for all $z\in L$ we have  $ad_x^r(z)\in K$. But $(ad_x)|_K$ is nilpotent, hence there exists $s$ such that $0=ad_x^s(ad_x^r(z))=(ad^{r+s}_x)(z)$ for all $z\in L$. By Engel's theorem $L$ is nilpotent.