# why is a Lie algebra not nilpotent even if an ideal is nilpotent and algebra quotient by ideal is nilpotent

Tags: lie-algebras, ideals, quotient-spaces, nilpotence

Why can't we use the same arguments as for solvability to say that If a Lie algebra $L$ has a nilpotent ideal $I$, and $L/I$ is nilpotent, then $L$ is nilpotent. Can someone point out the fallacy in the argument

Comment: Look over the solvability argument *carefully* to see why it doesn't translate. Right now you are asking why we cannot argue that cars have legs, given that horses have legs, and we can say that we ride horses and we ride cars. The argument also doesn't work for nilpotent groups: $S_3$ is an extension of an abelian group by an abelian group, but it is not nilpotent.

Comment: Agreeing with @ArturoMagidin, and you should take the easiest example of a non-nilpotent Lie algebra which has a nilpotent ideal with nilpotent quotient: The two-dimensional nonabelian one. Go through whatever proof you imagine line by line and check where it breaks in this example.

Comment: The [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545757/nilpotent-lie-algebras-are-closed-under-extensions/3548530#3548530) fails, because we really need the assumption that ${\rm ad}(x)|_I$ is nilpotent for all $x \in L$ - see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4441071/detail-in-the-proof-that-finite-dimensional-nilpotent-lie-algebras-are-closed-un?noredirect=1&lq=1).